# Vector addition with position vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces

This from Pressley Differential Geometry[image]

How is $$\delta(u)=\gamma(u)-v$$? Shouldn’t it be $$\delta(u)=v-\gamma(u)$$? If we consider the position vectors of $\gamma(u)$ and $v$.
$\delta(u)$ is the direction in which  $\gamma(u)$ is to be translated to form the ruled surface.

Comment: With the information given, we cannot know what would be the signification of $\delta$ and your question can't be answered

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. $\delta(u)$ is the direction in which  $\gamma(u)$ is to be translated to form the ruled surface.

Comment: The book is correct. You want to consider the point $P$ (corresponding to the vector $\mathbf v$) as the origin. Review the meaning/picture of subtraction of vectors.